# Not getting correct output in xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

I am using 2 xml files-"Department.xml" and "Employee.xml".

**Department.xml**

```
    <DeptList xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="officeSchema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Department>
    <deptName>mech</deptName>
    <deptNo>module1</deptNo>
    <deptManagerSSN>31001</deptManagerSSN>
    <deptManagerStartDate>2013-01-26</deptManagerStartDate>
    <deptLocation>near xyz road</deptLocation>
</Department>
<Department>
    <deptName>it</deptName>
    <deptNo>module2</deptNo>
    <deptManagerSSN>32001</deptManagerSSN>
    <deptManagerStartDate>2013-04-15</deptManagerStartDate>
    <deptLocation>near wt road</deptLocation>
</Department>
    </DeptList>
```

**Employee.xml**

```
    <EmpList xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="officeSchema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Employee>
    <empName>Ramesh</empName>
    <empSSN>31001</empSSN>
    <empSex>Male</empSex>
    <empSalary>57000</empSalary>
    <empBirthDate>1988-03-12</empBirthDate>
    <empDeptNo>module1</empDeptNo>
    <empSupervisorSSN>31001</empSupervisorSSN>
    <empAddress>3-f, x.y.z colony</empAddress>
    <empWorksOn>proj01</empWorksOn>
</Employee>
<Employee>
    <empName>Raj</empName>
    <empSSN>31002</empSSN>
    <empSex>Male    </empSex>
    <empSalary>40000</empSalary>
    <empBirthDate>1989-03-30</empBirthDate>
    <empDeptNo>Module1</empDeptNo>
    <empSupervisorSSN>31001</empSupervisorSSN>
    <empAddress>6-A, w.t.c. colony
    </empAddress>
    <empWorksOn>proj01</empWorksOn>
</Employee>
   </EmpList>
```

What I want is, if "deptManagerSSN" is equal to "empSSN" then print the "empName" else print "deptName". For this I have written the following query:

```
    for     $x in doc("C:/Users/Abhay/labWork/Department.xml")/DeptList/Department, 
            $y in doc("C:/Users/Abhay/labWork/Department.xml")/EmpList/Employee 
    return if(data($x/deptManagerSSN)=data($y/empSSN))
    then <text1>{data($y/emptName)}</text1> 
    else <text1>{data($x/deptName)}</text1>
```

But I am not getting any output. I am not getting any error also. Please tell where I am going wrong in query.
I am using "xml editix" as the xml engine.
Sorry, if my question is silly, I am new in xml.

Comment: I hope your actual query says `$y/empName`, not `$y/emptName` as you've shown it here.

Comment: @keshlam yes, sorry, I meant `$y/empName`, not `$y/emptName`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your logic is quite right. Maybe replacing

```
doc("C:/Users/
```

with

```
doc("/C:/Users/
```

will solve your problem?